# C# TryGet with Nullable Reference Annotation in .NET 4.x / Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Is there a way to polyfill nullable ref safety when using the `TryGet` type of methods with out parameters on .NET 4.x / .NET Standard 2.0?

As per [Try out Nullable Reference Types | .NET Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/) looks like [NotNullWhenAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute?view=net-5.0) is available in .NET Core / .NET 5+ / .NET Standard 2.1+ allowing the following.

```cs
public class MyString
{
    // True when 'value' is null
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty([NotNullWhen(false)] string? value)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class MyVersion
{
    // If it parses successfully, the Version will not be null.
    public static bool TryParse(string? input, [NotNullWhen(true)] out Version? version)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class MyQueue<T>
{
    // 'result' could be null if we couldn't Dequeue it.
    public bool TryDequeue([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T result)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Anyway to achieve something similar in a .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET 4.x library?

Comment: _Technically_, the source for these attributes and the code analysis that consumes them could be found, and (in theory) used to build a code analyzer that can run on .NET FW 4.x or .NET Standard 2.0.  A quick search on NuGet reveals that people seem to be doing this, though [the first library I looked at](https://github.com/manuelroemer/Nullable) didn't (at first glance) include source for a code analyzer - only source for the attributes.  Not sure how difficult the analyzer source would be to port back to .NET FW / Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple steps to use nullable reference types in a .NET Framework or .NET Standard 2.0 library:

- Copy the attributes from the [latest release](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Diagnostics/CodeAnalysis/NullableAttributes.cs) and use `#if` to only add the attribute to your targets ([NullableAttributes.cs](https://github.com/meziantou/Meziantou.Framework/blob/7fe1fc81ee48ca10b77e7b1e3c48f5cffd35f922/common/NullableAttributes.cs))
- Enable Nullable Reference Types `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` or `#nullable enable`

The BCL from .NET Framework is not annotated. A solution is to multitarget the project to get the latest annotations and disable nullable warning for older targets.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);nullable</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I wrote a post with more details: [How to use Nullable Reference Types in .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-use-nullable-reference-types-in-dotnet-standard-2-0-and-dotnet-.htm)

Comment: Will give this a try, albeit first via the NuGet library Sean Skelly proposed in a comment. And good shout about multi targeting for this as well to get BCL annotations!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not AFAIK and have personally tried, these attributes and features are only valid for

- .NET `5.0`, `6.0`, `Preview 7`
- .NET Core `3.0`, `3.1`
- .NET Standard `2.1`